# Using Git with ROS Groovy/rosws?

Tags: catkin, github, rosmake, git, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there something new/different about using git within rosws in ROS Groovy? It looks like I'm getting the stacks checked out but when I use rosmake it reports 0 of 0 stacks created.

Does the catkin workspace effect this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61947/using-git-with-ros-groovy/rosws?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-01**:
Please update your question showing exactly what you did. What does `rosws info` show?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-02**:
Also update what exactly you did with which packages. In principle there is nothing different, but the packages you were using might have been catkinized for groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Packages were catkinized for groovy. Need to use catkin commands (wstool set) instead of older apt-get process.

---

Originally posted by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) with karma: 160 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0